# Mail Merge given Word Templates with given Data Sources in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mailmerge

I am looking for a way how to merge a **given** data source with a **given** word template in C#/.NET. After merging, I want to save the whole document as DOCX or PDF or whatever.

**The files I have are:**

- TemplateA.docx
- SourceForTemplateA.csv
- TemplateB.docx
- SourceForTemplateB.csv

and so on...

These templates are very simple. Just a few merge fields and that's it. No "IF" conditions or whatsover.

Of course I could do all this in WORD file by file, but as I have so many Template/Source pairs, that's not really an option. I found many 3rd party libraries which seem to offer such a feature (among many others), but they all cost a fortune.

Also a hint where to start (for example a built-in library to watch out for) would be already great :-)

Answer (score -2):

The [.NET Word Framework](https://www.syncfusion.com/document-processing/word-framework/net) is a high-performance and feature-rich framework that processes advanced Word document operations more quickly without depending on Microsoft Office or interop dependencies. With the help of the Word creation and editing library provided by this framework, Word documents can be created, read, and edited programmatically in any.NET application. You can find the documentation link below,

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/working-with-mail-merge

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: Yes, I found that, but 999 Dollars is what I call a fortune as I said. That doesn’t help me.